# TypeError: undefined is not a function, js engine: hermes

Tags: react-native, metro-bundler, react-native-hermes

My React Native (0.66.3) app today pops up an error with a stable code which hasn't had any change for quite some time. It is on macOS Big Sur. Here is the error:

```
 ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not a function, js engine: hermes
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xyz_app5/http:/localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.xyz-app5'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:498:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:394:35)
    at getCodeFrame (/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xyz_app5/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:919:18)
    at Server._symbolicate (/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xyz_app5/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:992:22)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async Server._processRequest (/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xyz_app5/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:403:7) {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xyz_app5/http:/localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.xyz-app5'
}
```

Here is the error displayed on IOS simulator:

[image]

The error seems related to metro in React Native.

Comment: Looks like you are using keyboard-aware-scroll-view, if so, can you tell which version you are using. Also try to upgrade it and check.

Comment: Hi `Akshay Shenoy`, which module the keyboard-aware-scroll-view comes with? It is not in the package.json

Comment: It is "1.0.1". Found it under @codler

Comment: Upgraded to 2.0.0 and error disappeared. Many thanks.

Comment: Without any change, exactly same error came back again after reloading the app. Re-installing didn't solve the problem. Very strange.

Comment: hey @user938363 did you figure out the issue?

Comment: Reinstalling the app worked for me have you tried it?

Comment: @AkshayShenoy How could you say that issue was because of `keyboard-aware-scroll-view`?

Comment: @user938363 Any update of the issue since your last comment? It can help a lot of other developers

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall node_modules

```
 rm -rf node_modules
```

Clean your cache

```
 yarn cache clean (or npm cache clean –force)
```